# Fooman Speedster Advanced not working after migration to 1.9 from 1.8

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I upgraded my 1.8 installation to 1.9 - during which everything was successful, however my website would only load a blank page.

After some troubleshooting, I traced the problem down to the Fooman Speedster Advanced module. By disabling it, the site came back to life.

I've removed, reinstalled I just cannot get it to work anymore.

On my most recent attempt to re-enable it I received a *There has been an error processing your request": **Module "Fooman_SpeedsterAdvanced" requires module "Fooman_Common"**

Can anyone point me in the right direction, the minification is a great feature.

**Note: I understand that we are not supposed to post questions about modules, I have seen in the past that questions with active developers have been permitted**

Comment: Have you contact with that Support Of Fooman?

Comment: You are always going to be better off contacting the developer for third party module questions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module support

Comment: Fooman posts here and there are MANY questions about fooman modules (http://magento.stackexchange.com/search?q=fooman); there is even a fooman-extention tag...

Comment: Interesting that Magento Connect allows you to download the update - the extension is currently marked as inactive until we have the dependency working. For now please downgrade to the version you previously used.

Comment: @Fooman. Please vote to reopen this question (if you can) and add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting that Magento Connect allows you to download the update - the extension is currently marked as inactive until we have the dependency working. For now please downgrade to the version you previously used.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to install the Fooman_common extension.  Its available on github: https://github.com/fooman/common